# Gauss divergence application correct or not

Tags: volume, surface-integrals, divergence-operator, multiple-integral

Let $W$ be the region inside the solid cylinder $x^2+y^2\leq 4$ between the planes $z=0$ and the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$. Let $S$ be the boundary of $W$. Evaluate$$\int\int_S\vec{F}.\hat{n}dS$$ where $\vec{F}=(x^2+y^2-4)\hat{i}+3xy\hat{j}+(2xz+z^2)\hat{k}$ and $\hat{n}$ is the outward normal.
I calculate the divergence of $F$ i.e $div(\vec{F})=7x+2z$ and used the Gauss Divergence theorem so i got $$\int\int_{Circle\;Radius\leq 2}\int_{0}^{x^2+y^2}7x+2z \;dzdxdy$$ is my approach right. can anybody explain if it is right why can we apply gauss divergence theorem, i still can't convince myself

Comment: I think it's all right. It's just a cylinder cut by a paraboloid and the xy-plane. So to evaluate the volume you have to integrate the circle ($0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $ 0 \le \phi \le pi$) and then take it from the bottom to the paraboloid ($0 \le z \le x^2+y^2$) integrating $1$. But to use the divergence theorem you have to use the divergent of the field instead of one, because you are relating the divergence of the field and the solid itself.

Comment: Yes i have used the divergence of the vector field